# Forbid extension methods

Tags: c#

I am publishing a public class as part of my C# framework for users to be able to register within my application. I don't want users to extend my class so I marked it `sealed`. Now I have some users reporting that they see more methods in that class than the ones I provided. After some investigation, it appeared that these users have defined extension methods that show (by intellisense) just like if they were defined in my public sealed class.

**Question**
Is there a way I can forbid users to define extension methods on my public sealed class?

Comment: I'm curious... Why would you forbid them to write extension methods? After all, they can only call public members of your class from extension methods.

Comment: Another way of framing your question is "is there any way I can forbid people to write a static method, on their own static class, that takes  my object as a first parameter" (extension methods are syntactic sugar around this). The answer of course is no.

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic I want to avoid intellisense noise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't. I can't see why you'd want to, to be honest. If you have users who *want* to use extension methods, let them do so. No-one's going to *force* them to do so, and it may make their life easier. At least as your type is sealed, you know that if anyone reports unexpectedly-available methods, they *must* be extension methods.

Note that anyone can define an extension method on `object`, and that would *always* be available, even if there were a way of prohibiting extension methods on just your class.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I just want to keep my class looking clean in intellisense

Comment: @GETah: The way I see it, it will be your own users making it "dirty" - so leave it up to them. If they want a "clean" Intellisense, they shouldn't add the extension methods. If they don't, who are you to stop them?